# log shipping replication in one machine

Tags: postgresql, log-shipping

We have install postgresql version 9.3 in ubuntu. We want to ask is it possible to do log shipping replication in one machine with different port? We also  tried that process in one machine but still get   an error in slave such as

**warning : connection to the database failed, disabling startup checks :
psql: FATAL : the database system is starting up**

We do the the log shipping replication process based on http://www.themagicnumber.es/replication-in-postgresql-i?lang=en

We hope all of you can help us to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can replicate between two servers on the same machine.

Presumably your slave isn't set up to allow connections (the phrase to search for is "hot standby").

Random website tutorials about replication are nice, but do take the time to read the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply, that is means that we have to configure in slave to "hot standby"? but we already set the wal level as "archive"? it is true that we had done?